# Sieve saved EICAR virus to Junk folder but also disregarded in the log

Tags: postfix, dovecot, clamav, sieve

I have setup my own mail server by partially following the guide (series) [here](http://arstechnica.com/business/2014/03/taking-e-mail-back-part-3-fortifying-your-box-against-spammers/3/)

The sieve filter rule is:

```
... truncated ...
# Trash messages with improperly formed message IDs
if not header :regex "message-id" ".*@.*\\." {
    fileinto :create "Junk";
}

if header :contains "X-Virus-Status" "Infected" {
    discard;
    stop;
}

if header :contains "X-Spam-Level" "*****" {
    fileinto :create "Junk";
    setflag "\\Seen";
}
```

And I compiled it right after the change. Restarted Dovecot.

Still, I see the log:

```
2016-05-16 22:01:43 lda(mail@example.com): Info: sieve: msgid=emailsecuritycheck.net.2.becsz*6nYwm7BtlKdQRYXg==: stored mail into mailbox 'Junk'
2016-05-16 22:01:43 lda(mail@example.com): Info: sieve: msgid=emailsecuritycheck.net.2.becsz*6nYwm7BtlKdQRYXg==: marked message to be discarded if not explicitly delivered (discard action)
```

I was using the EICAR testing service from [here](http://www.emailsecuritycheck.net).

When I used [this](https://www.heise.de/security/dienste/emailcheck/virendummies/send-url-eicar/) service, sieve is working properly (disregard straightly)

Do you have any idea why do I still see the email rather than just discard it?

The 2nd email contains the test virus, is not a spam email, and its virus header is:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=XXX
X-Virus-Scanned: clamav-milter 0.99.1 at mail.example.com
X-Virus-Status: Infected (Eicar-Test-Signature)
```